# In feature engineering, is using x*y as an interaction term different from using x/y?

Tags: logistic, interaction, feature-engineering

I want to engineer some new features for a classifier, say, logistic regression. Let's say I have two continuous (numeric) features $x$ and $y$. I know that you can create a new feature from $x$ and $y$ by multiplying them, i.e., $x*y$. So then you have $$ z = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 y + \beta_3 xy $$

And I see this in literature a lot.

What about using $x/y$? Would using this instead of the multiple $xy$ change the accuracy of the classifier? Could it be beneficial to have both interaction terms (if you can call them that)? Or is it redundant?

Comment: `x/y` = x*(1/y). Am I correct?

Comment: Right... are you suggesting then it's basically the same thing? `xy` and `x/y`?

Comment: If `y` and `1/y` looks the same thing to you.

Comment: it is a bit late for you but in those models I have experienced that x/y can add some information too !

Comment: I feel a better approach would be to DO the work, experiment, and then ask if the models are more or less appropriate after looking at the numbers. Yes, taking a reciprocal is different from a quadratic transform, but one has to try it first to find out. I am sometimes surprised by the questions that get past moderators.